# OrientDB Studio - trying to get to first base

Tags: orientdb

OrientDB Studio looked to be a promising tool to explore the product for use as an object store replacement for db4o, but I unfortunately I have not been able to get to first base with it.

I am running OSX 10.6.8.  The behavior described below was observed with both the 1.7.10 Mac and the 1.7.9 "all platforms" binaries:

1) I am not able to create a database with Studio.  I edited the root password and restarted the server but any attempt to create a new database using Studio yields the same result: 401 Unauthorized.

And there is not much information in the logs:

```
2014-11-20 12:12:32:420 CONF Remote client connected from: OClientConnection [id=1, source=?, since=1416503552420] [OClientConnectionManager]
2014-11-20 12:12:32:431 FINE [ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.execute] Requested: POST /database/invoices/local/document [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]
2014-11-20 12:12:32:438 FINE Disconnecting connection with id=1 [OClientConnectionManager]
2014-11-20 12:12:32:438 FINE Disconnected connection with id=1, no other active channels found [OClientConnectionManager]
2014-11-20 12:12:32:438 FINE Connection shutdowned [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]
```

I had to resort to creating the new database using the console.  Having to resort to using the console steepens the learning curve and is a barrier to adoption.

2) I would like to use Studio to create indexes and explore index behavior, but I do not seem to be able to open **any** database, even the demo GratefulDeadConcerts, as writer or admin.

Studio displays the mode (reader) at the top right of the page, and I have to believe I have no write privileges because I am not able to create any indexes on my new object database.

Any help would be Gratefully (pun intended) appreciated.

Comment: I've just downloaded ODB 1.7.10 Mac run the server, and i was able to open GratefulDeadConcerts with admin/admin and create a new database.
Are you able to login with admin/admin in GratefulDeadConcerts db?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is apparently not with either OrientDB or Studio.

1) I continued to test with OSX 1.7.10.  Logging in as admin/admin, I noticed that Safari would open the databases as (admin) but Firefox would open the databases as (reader).  After upgrading to Firefox 33.1.1 the mode now shows as (admin) **and** I am now able to create databases using Studio.

I just deleted localhost cookies in Safari 5.1.10 and was able to create a database using that browser as well.  It's possible that step may required after changing the root password and restarting the server.

2) My problem with index creation was due to lack of understanding of how indexes work.  Indexes can only be created on objects with schema-defined properties.

After opening the database and requesting schema generation using the API, Studio displayed class properties and I was able to create indexes on those properties in Studio.

```
  db2 = new OObjectDatabaseTx("remote:localhost/invoices").open("admin", "admin");

// Tell OrientDB to automatically generate schema during class registration, this saves us some code.
  db2.setAutomaticSchemaGeneration(true);

// Now register our classes...

  db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClasses("your.entity.package.goes.here");

// Save the schema of our new database...

  db2.getMetadata().getSchema().save();
```